# vuex unknown action type: showRegisterLogin/show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I wrote the following code but it shows an error.  What is the reason for this?

**Error**

> [vuex] unknown action type: showRegisterLogin/show

**HomePage.vue**   *// component*

When using the sh method This error is caused

```
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  components: {
    RegisterLogin
  },

  data() {
    return {}
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      showRegisterLogin: state => state.showRegisterLogin.show
    }),
  },

  methods: {
    sh() {
      this.$store.dispatch('showRegisterLogin/show');
    }
  }
}
```

**/ store / modules / showRegisterLogin.js**

```
// States
const state = {
    show: false,
};

// Getters
const getter = {
    show (state) {
        return state.show;
    }
};

// Mutations
const mutation = {
    showPage (state) {
        return state.show = true;
    },
    hidePage (state) {
        return state.show = false;
    }
};

// Actions
const action = {
    show({ commit }) {
        commit('showPage');
    },
    hide({ commit }) {
        commit('hidePage');
    }
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getter,
    mutation,
    action
}
```

**/ store / store.js**

```
'use strict';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import showRegisterLogin from "./modules/showRegisterLogin";

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        showRegisterLogin,
    }
});
```

I also imported the store.js file into app.js and registered it in new vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the store, module, and component are fine, except for the name of the store objects in your module:

- `getter` should be `getters`
- `mutation` should be `mutations`
- `action` should be `actions`

Probably just typos.  Those can't be arbitrarily named since Vuex looks specifically for those keys.